# How to refresh TextField containing Binding variable when original variable is changed SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

There are some similar questions to mine, but I haven't seen anything that answers exactly what I am looking for. In `SwiftUI`, I have a form that sends data to an API when a button is pressed. However, I am looking for this form to reset once the form successfully sends the data. My send data function returns a `Result`, so in the Result `.success` I try to reset the values that populate the `TextField`:

```
switch result {
case.success(_):
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.inputTime = 0
        self.arrivalTime = Date()
        self.seatedTime = Date()
        reload()
}
```

(There is a `.failure` case also, but I don't thing that it would be relevant to include it). The `reload()` function just re-retrieves the data that the user just sent in with the form. Here is my Form:

```
Form {
    TextField("WaitTime", value: $inputTime, formatter: numberFormatter)
    DatePicker("Arrival Time", selection: $arrivalTime, displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
    DatePicker("Seated Time", selection: $seatedTime, displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
}
```

The three variables are declared at the top of the view like so:

```
@State var inputTime: Int = 0
@State var arrivalTime: Date = Date()
@State var seatedTime: Date = Date()
```

Resetting the variables like `inputTime` does not change the value in the `TextField`, controlled by the `Binding` `$inputTime`. I am not sure how to get these form fields to reset. Is there a better way to do this? Thank you for any help!

Comment: iOS? macOS? is TextField in focus? does reload() also change inputTime?

Comment: How and where are déclarés the 3 vars ? You may have some mismatch between state and /or binding

Comment: I think you are missing the case in the switch?  `case let .success(response):`  also the `self.inputTime = 0` should be `self.inputTime = "0"`

Comment: @PtitXav I edited it so the post now contains the code that declares the variables.

Comment: @Asperi This is with iOS. I have no modifiers on the TextField that say whether it is in focus or not at the moment. reload() does not change inputTime.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The `$inputTime` in the `TextField` was not updating because it was still in focus. So, in the success case, I changed the boolean variable of `inputFieldInFocus` to `false`. Then, using the `.focused` modifier, the TextField was no longer in focus so its value could then be updated.

```
switch result {
case.success(_):
    inputFieldInFocus = false
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.inputTime = 0
        self.arrivalTime = Date()
        self.seatedTime = Date()
        reload()
}
```

```
TextField("WaitTime", value: $inputTime, formatter: numberFormatter)
                                    .focused($inputFieldInFocus)
```

```
@FocusState var inputFieldInFocus: Bool
```